# Execute multipe PHP scripts simultaneously

Tags: php, linux, shell

Okay I have 50 php scripts each of which will take 20 days to finish I want to write a PHP script to run these 50 scripts simultaneously I did use exec() function in my script but the problem is it runs first script and wait until it is finished before executing the next script. I want to run all of them in parallel.Is there any way to do that? 
Thanks

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169326/calling-multiple-bash-scripts-and-running-them-in-parallel-not-in-sequence

Answer (score 1):

Okay thanks I got my answer after a lot of search

Apart from adding a `&`, you also need to redirect output to somewhere - otherwise your php process waits until the other process finished, because there could be more output:

```
exec('/path/to/program & > /dev/null 2>&1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You put a `&` between scripts

```
php /var/www/script1.php & php /var/www/script2.php ........
```

Answer (score 0):

if have to use only php,  more "php'iish" way to do this is Robo (https://robo.li) it is used with codeception, for example.